# More than one QGLWidget simultaneous doesn't work for a video usage

Tags: qt, opengl, qglwidget

I have a problem if I want to display a video using `QGLWidget`. With one instance it works, but it doesn't and widgets are black with multi-occurrence (usage in `QGridLayout` for example).

I subclass `QGLWidget` that way to play a video (by refreshing the `QPixmap` I want to show using my `setCurrentImage` method):

```
class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GLWidget(QGLWidget* shareWidget = 0, QWidget* parent = 0)
        : QGLWidget(parent, shareWidget)
    {
        //...
        // I do this because the QPixmap to refresh is produced in a different thread than UI thread.
        connect(this, SIGNAL(updated()), this SLOT(update()));
    }

    //...

    void setCurrentImage(const QPixmap& pixmap)
    {
        m_mutex.lock();
        m_pixmap = pixmap;
        m_mutex.unlock();

        emit updated();
    }

protected:
    void initializeGL()
    {
        static const int coords[4][2] = {{ +1, -1 }, { -1, -1 }, { -1, +1 }, { +1, +1 }};
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
            m_texCoords.append(QVector2D(j == 0 || j == 3, j == 0 || j == 1));
            m_vertices.append(QVector2D(0.5 * coords[j][0], 0.5 * coords[j][1]));
        }

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

#define PROGRAM_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE 0
#define PROGRAM_TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE 1

        QGLShader* vShader = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Vertex, this);
        const char* szVShaderCode = /*...*/;
        vShader->compileSourceCode(szVShaderCode);

        QGLShader *fShader = new QGLShader(QGLShader::Fragment, this);
        const char* szFShaderCode = /*...*/;
        fShader->compileSourceCode(szFShaderCode);

        m_pProgram = new QGLShaderProgram(this);
        m_pProgram->addShader(vShader);
        m_pProgram->addShader(fShader);
        m_pProgram->bindAttributeLocation("vertex", PROGRAM_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE);
        m_pProgram->bindAttributeLocation("texCoord", PROGRAM_TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE);
        m_pProgram->link();

        m_pProgram->bind();
        m_pProgram->setUniformValue("texture", 0);
    }

    void paintGL()
    {
        qglClearColor(Qt::black);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // I use some uniform values to "modify" image
        m_pProgram->setUniformValue(/*...*/);
        //...

        QMatrix4x4 m;
        m.ortho(-0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f, 4.0f, 15.0f);
        m.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);

        m_pProgram->setUniformValue("matrix", m);
        m_pProgram->enableAttributeArray(PROGRAM_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE);
        m_pProgram->enableAttributeArray(PROGRAM_TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE);
        m_pProgram->setAttributeArray(PROGRAM_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE, m_vertices.constData());
        m_pProgram->setAttributeArray(PROGRAM_TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE, m_texCoords.constData());

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);        
    }

    void resizeGL(int iWidth, int iHeight)
    {
        glViewport(0, 0, iWidth, iHeight);
    }

private slots:
    void update()
    {
        QPixmap pixmap;

        m_mutex.lock();
        pixmap = m_pixmap;
        m_mutex.unlock();

        m_texture = bindTexture(pixmap, GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        updateGL();
    }

private:
    QMutex m_mutex;
    QPixmap m_pixmap;

    QVector<QVector2D> m_vertices;
    QVector<QVector2D> m_texCoords;
    QGLShaderProgram* m_pProgram;
};
```

Then, to simulate a multi thread rendering (each thread produces its own video images), I wrote these little classes.

The image producer class:

```
class ImageProducer : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ImageProducer(QGLWidget* pGLWidget)
        : QThread(pGLWidget), m_pGLWidget(pGLWidget)
    {
        m_pixmap = QPixmap("fileName.jpg");
        m_bMustStop = false;
    }

protected:
    void run()
    {
        while(!m_bMustStop){
            static_cast<GLWidget*>(m_pGLWidget)->setCurrentImage(m_pixmap);

            // Simulate a frame rate
            msleep(1000 / /*FRAME_RATE*/);
        }
    }

private:
    QGLWidget* m_pGLWidget;
    QPixmap m_pixmap;
    bool m_bMustStop;
};
```

And the rendering class:

```
#define ROWS 1
#define COLS 1

class Window : public QWidget
{
public:
    Window()
    {
        QGridLayout* pMainLayout = new QGridLayout(this);
        setLayout(pMainLayout);

        for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j){
                QGLWidget* pGLWidget = new GLWidget();
                pMainLayout->addWidget(pGLWidget, i, j);

                ImageProducer* pImageProducer = new ImageProducer(pGLWidget);
                pImageProducer->start();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Ok stop with code samples ^^ Problem is with *ROWS = 1* and *COLS = 1* (see `Window` class) it works, but I have black widgets with other values... I'm lost, what do I miss?

Thanks!

**EDIT: (context is always multi-GLWidget instance, all works fine with only one)**

Strange thing I just discover: I overrode `QGLWidget`'s `mouseMoveEvent` (so, in my `GLWidget` class) which simply calls `updateGL();`. And fact is when I press and move the mouse with the current code nothing happens. But if I replace (in my `ImageProducer`'s `run()` method):

```
static_cast<GLWidget*>(m_pGLWidget)->setCurrentImage(m_pixmap);
```

By

```
static_cast<GLWidget*>(m_pGLWidget)->setCurrentImage(QPixmap("fileName.jpg"));
```

The image is refreshed in the current component as long as I move the mouse. When I release it, or do it in an other components, the background become black again.

Comment: Can't test the code right now, but just to ensure the GL context creation is correct, if you change clear color say, to red ( qglClearColor(Qt::red); ) do you see multiple red GLWidgets?

Comment: @S.Monteleone Thanks for your answer! Hmm no, my components still have a black background (no red, neither red blinking). **EDIT:** Well not exactly! In my `paintGL` method, if I let only the first two lines (but with Qt::red) instead of Qt::black), I see red background!!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So the GL context is ok. What about the pixmap you use in the update method ? Is it all black? You can check it by adding a call to the save method there.

Comment: @S.Monteleone Good idea, but no problem. Saving a pixmap (5Mpx photography to be precise) to a file in my `update()` method works fine. But, I discover something strange and I have edited my post! Maybe a clue, something about a cache...?

Comment: I didn't notice your imageproducer is a qthread. Qpixmap isn't thread safe and isn't meant to be used outside the GUI thread. Have you tried with a qimage instead?

Comment: I just tested, but using `QImage` didn't change anything. But you're right, and to use `QPixmap` as I do, I had to add this instruction `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_X11InitThreads);`.

Comment: Ok then try calling the base QGLWidget::update() method in your update() overload. It may be due to the backbuffer, which is invalidated when you move the mouse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169601/discussion-between-n0un-and-s-monteleone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am writing down the answer after a chat with the OP, for the benefit of others. Here are the main topics that lead to a resolution of the issue.*

**Note**: At the time of writing, the Qt OpenGL module is **deprecated** and its usage is discouraged. According to the official [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-module.html#details) the suggested approach is to use the OpenGL* classes in the GUI module.

## Textures

The main issue with the code above is essentially due to the way the textures are handled.

First of all, the **bindTexture()** method does not **bind** in OpenGL terms, but actually **create** the OpenGL texture and upload the data passed as argument to it (*QImage* or *QPixmap*). That is confusing and can lead to serious issues. In the code posted by the OP, he is essentially **leaking** memory allocating a new texture at each frame update.

To ensure you are not leaking memory, you should at the least release the previously allocated texture, calling [QGLWidget::deleteTexture](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qglwidget.html#deleteTexture).

However, it is worth to note that there are better approaches to avoid unnecessary **memory fragmentation** and **inefficiency**. In this case, the best approach is to allocate the texture **once** and simply update its content when necessary. This may not be possible directly with the API offered by the old Qt OpenGL module, but you can always mix Qt and *native* OpenGL code.

## Context handling

Another issue is the way OpenGL context is handled. As a rule of thumb, one should always ensure the correct context is **current** before issuing commands to the OpenGL implementation. Sometimes, Qt does this for you automatically (i.e. before calling the **paintGL()** method).

In this case, we need to explicitly make the QGLWidget's context the current context before calling the bindTexture method, otherwise it will effect the **last** context that was made current. That is why only the last widget was showing something untill somewhone was triggering a makeCurrent call by interacting with the other widgets.

## Threading

There are a couple of issues here. First of all, it is not safe to use a **QPixmap** object in a thread other than the GUI thread. QPixmap is designed to optimize pixmap blitting on screen. In this case, the pixmap is really just the frame to be uploaded to the OpenGL implementation, which handles all the rendering. So it is safe to use a QImage instead.

The other issue is that the **GLWidget::setCurrentImage()** and thus, the **bindTexture** method, are called directly from the **run()** method of the *ImageProducer* thread. This can't be because we need to make the widget context current, but it is not possible to call *makeCurrent()* from a thread other than the GUI thread (more details [here](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qglcontext.html)).

A possible approach to solve this issue is to add a signal to ImageProducer to notify the frame has been updated, and connect this signal to the *setCurrentImage()* slot. Qt's signal-slot mechanism will ensure that the setCurrentImage is executed in the GLWidget thread, that is the GUI thread.

## Code

Here are the suggested (and tested) modifications to the code posted above.

**ImageProduer class**

add the signal:

```
 void imageUpdated(const QImage &image);
```

and emit it when the frame is updated:

```
void ImageProducer::run()
{
    while(!m_bMustStop){
        QImage frame(m_pixmap.width(), m_pixmap.height(), m_pixmap.format());
        QPainter painter(&frame);
        painter.drawImage(QPoint(), m_pixmap);
        painter.setFont(QFont("sans-serif", 22));
        painter.setPen(Qt::white);
        painter.drawText(20, 50, QString("Frame: %1").arg(QString::number(_frameCount)));
        painter.end();

        emit imageUpdated(frame);

        msleep(1000 / FRAME_RATE);

        _frameCount++;
    }
}
```

**GLWidget class**

ensure the setCurrentImage method handle the OpenGL context and destroy the old texture:

```
void GLWidget::setCurrentImage(const QImage& pixmap)
{
    m_mutex.lock();
    m_pixmap = pixmap;
    m_mutex.unlock();

    makeCurrent();

    deleteTexture(m_texture);
    m_texture = bindTexture(pixmap, GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    doneCurrent();

    emit updated();
}
```

Comment: I just have an optional question: do you know why, if I add `QGLContext::NoBindOption` to that `bindTexture(pixmap, GL_TEXTURE_2D);` function to improve perf, there is no image but a black screen?

Comment: Maybe the driver does not support non power of two textures. But that is just a wild guess. I would suggest to use some OGL debugging tool to check what is happening, like [vogl](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/vogl).